# Multiple task with one button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext, imageview, spinner

```
 EditText e = (EditText)findViewById(Edit_current);
    Spinner s = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.edit_destination);
    navigatebut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.navigate);
    final String current = e.getText().toString();
    final String dest = s.getSelectedItem().toString();
    navigatebut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //to do your drawable
            if (current.equals("Entrance") && dest.equals("Vegetables")) {
                layout.setImageResource(R.drawable.entrance_vege);;
                //do something
            }

        }
    });
}}
```

[image: How it looks like]

---

When i run this, it has an error java.lang.nullpointerexception. 
May I know where its coming from?

---

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.sp.ez_mart, PID: 17820
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sp.ez_mart/com.sp.ez_mart.NavigateImage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.sp.ez_mart.NavigateImage.onCreate(NavigateImage.java:31)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: `com.sp.ez_mart.NavigateImage.onCreate(NavigateImage.java:31)` what is at line # `31`?

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace clearly tells you where the error is @ `NavigateImage.java Line#31`

Looking at code, it seems like you are passing wrong **resource id** in following line. May be you meant to use `R.id.edit_destination`

```
EditText e = (EditText)findViewById(Edit_current);
```

So, I suspect, it is crashing from

```
final String current = e.getText().toString();
```

Because it can't find the `EditText` **e**.

*NOTE: In future as best practice, please use descriptive variable names.*